# Code working in fiddle and browser but not in sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

https://jsfiddle.net/rurounisena/zrab1u8q/74/
UPDATED LINK

The above fiddle looks and does exactly what I need it to do. The HTML is copied exactly from a table in sharepoint. However when I try to jslink this code to the actual sharepoint page the below happens.

[link to sharepoint result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf6R1.jpg)

Here is the code is the js.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(document).ready(function(){
    j( "span.ms-noWrap" ).wrapInner( "<span class='dates'></span>");
    j( "td.ms-vb-lastCell" ).wrapInner( "<span class='status'>
    </span>");
});

j(document).ready(function(){
    var status = j("span.status");

    status.each(function(index) {
        if (j(this).text() == "Received") {
            j(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
        }
   });
});

j(document).ready(function(){
    const orgDates = j('span.dates');
    var message = '';

    orgDates.each((i, elem) => {
        let parts = j(elem).text().split('/');
        let dt = new Date(parts[2] ,parts[0] - 1, parts[1]).getTime();
        let diffdate = Math.floor((dt - new Date().getTime()) / (86400 * 1000));

        if (isNaN(diffdate)) {
            return 0;
        }

        console.log(elem);

        if(dt > new Date().getTime() || j(elem).parents('tr').find('span.status').text() == 'Received' ){
            var nogood = diffdate;

            if(nogood) {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        if((diffdate+2) < 1) {
            if((diffdate+2) == 0) {
                diffdate = (diffdate+1) + ' day ago';
            }else {
                diffdate = (diffdate+1) + ' days ago';
            }
        }

        diffdate = diffdate.toString().slice(1);

        message +=  j(elem).parents('tr').find("a.ms-listlink").text() + ' ' + j(elem).parents('tr').find("td:nth-child(4)").text() + ' was due ' + diffdate + '<br/>';

    });

    j.alert({
        theme: 'my-theme',
        title: 'The following bulk is past the expected received date:',
        content: message
    });
});
```

I don't understand why this code works everywhere except sharepoint. Can someone please help or at least point me in the right direction?

UPDATE: 
logging the diffdate after 1st if statement in fiddle:

- -52
- NaN
- -30
- -38

logging the diffdate after 1st if statement in sharepoint:

- -52
- -43
- NaN
- -42
- -32
- -31
- NaN
- -32
- -49
- NaN
- -45
- -49
- -46
- -35
- -30
- -38
- -56
- -49
- -46
- -44
- -39
- -38
- -36
- -32
- -56
- -46

Comment: Can you show what is being logged for `parts` in your SharePoint loop please?

Comment: Array(3)0: "9"1: "5"2: "2018"length: 3__proto__: Array(0)
 Array(3)
 Array(1)
 Array(3)
Array(3)
 Array(3)
Array(3)
 Array(3)
 Array(1)
Array(3)
 Array(3)
 Array(1)
 Array(1)
 Array(3)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
j( "span.ms-noWrap" )
```

is picking up something else on your page. It's a common class in SharePoint and can't be relied on a a selector in this way; for this and other reasons, it's considered suboptimal to "read" your data from SharePoint's output. A better solution might to be to fetch items from the server directly via the object model.

You can find a Microsoft guide to that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint#sharepoint-list-item-tasks).

Comment: Would I be able to do that even if I'm not an admin?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! Just put the code in the page in a script editor or content editor and it will work for any user with read access to the list.